# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I cannot understand where the single quote coming from the json format.

This is the ajax

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("form#saveForm").validate({
        debug: true,
        onkeyup: false,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var form = new FormData($("#saveForm")[0]);
            console.log(form);
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "<?php echo base_url('admin_seo_controller/assignDomainToUser/'); ?>",
                data: new FormData($("#saveForm")[0]),
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    jdata = $.parseJSON(data);
                    console.log(jdata);
                    if (jdata.status_code == 200) {
                        $("#d_conf_msg").empty().html("<p>Success!</p>").dialog('open');
                    } else {
                        $("#d_notif_msg").empty().html("<p>" + jdata.status_desc + "</p>").dialog('open');
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        rules: {
            file: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            file: "This is field is required!"
        }
    });

});
```

This is the json format that output

```
'{"status_code":200,"status_desc":"Success!"}
```

Error is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0
 at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
```

And this is the data of the json that I am trying to encode

```
$response = array(
            'status_code' => 200,
            'status_desc' => 'Success!'
            );
```

Hoping someone can help me.

Comment: `'{"` extra `'` at the beginning. How you are returning the data?

Comment: In PHP method I returned data by " echo json_encode($response);  "

Comment: Check your PHP code. Seems you're sending a single-quote character to the output buffer before your JSON. You should only have something like `header('Content-type: application/json'); echo json_encode($response); exit;`

Comment: Search any other `echo` that can send `'` in beginning

Comment: Check for anything that might have accidentally been typed before an opening PHP tag, eg `'<?php ...`